# F# merge CSV files with different columns

Tags: csv, f#

I'm fairly new to F# but I'm fascinated about it and want to apply it to some applications. Currently, I have multiple csv files which is just timestamp and some sensor's values, the timestamp is unique but the columns values' are different.
For example I have two csv file

csv1:

```
timestamp, sensor1
time1, 1.0
```

csv2:

```
timestamp, sensor1, sensor2
time2, 2.0, 3.0
```

The result I want is

```
timestamp, sensor1, sensor2
time1, 1.0, 
time2, 2.0, 3.0
```

I wonder if any easy way to do it in F#. Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**
Here my current solution which involves using *LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv* (https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorksCsvReader) to parse csv to Data.DataTable and *Deedle* (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Deedle) to convert Data.DataTable to Frame and use the SaveCsv method to save to csv files.

```
open System.IO
open System
open LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv
open Deedle

// get list of csv files
let filelist = expression_to_get_list_of_csv_file_path

// func to readCsv from path and return Data.DataTable
let funcReadCSVtoDataTable (path:string) = 
    use csv = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(path), true)
    let tmpdata = new Data.DataTable()
    tmpdata.Load(csv)
    tmpdata        

// map list of file paths to get list of datatable
let allTables = List.map funcReadCSVtoDataTable filelist

// create allData table to iterate over the list
let allData = new Data.DataTable()
List.iter (fun (x:Data.DataTable) -> allData.Merge(x)) allTables

//convert datatable to Deedle Frame and save to csv file
let df = Frame.ReadReader (allData.CreateDataReader())   
df.SaveCsv("./final_csv.csv")
```

The reason for using *LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv* is because I need to parse a few thousands of files at the same time, and according to this article (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F) *LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv* is the fastest.

**UPDATE 2: FINAL SOLUTION**
Thanks to Tomas about the RowsKey map solution (see his comment below), I re-twisted his code for the case of list of files

```
// get list of csv files
let filelist = expression_to_get_list_of_csv_file_path

// function to merge two Frames
let domerge (df0:Frame<int,string>) (df1:Frame<int,string>) = 
    df1 
    |> Frame.mapRowKeys (fun k-> k+df0.Rows.KeyCount)
    |> Frame.merge df0

// read filelist to Frame list 
let dflist = filelist |> List.map (fun (x:string)-> Frame.ReadCsv x)

// using List.fold to "fold" through the list with dflist.[0] is the intial state
let dffinal = List.tail dflist |> List.fold domerge (List.head dflist)
dffinal.SaveCsv("./final_csv.csv")
```

Now the code looks "functional", however, I get a small warning of Frame.ReadCsv that the method is not meant for F#, but it works anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to use an external library, then you can do this very easily using the [data frame manipulation library called Deedle](http://fslab.org/Deedle/). Deedle lets you read data frames from CSV files and when you merge data frames, it makes sure to align column and row keys for you:

```
open Deedle

let f1 = Frame.ReadCsv("c:/temp/f1.csv")
let f2 = Frame.ReadCsv("c:/temp/f2.csv")

let merged = 
  f2 
  |> Frame.mapRowKeys (fun k -> k + f1.Rows.KeyCount)
  |> Frame.merge f1

merged.SaveCsv("c:/temp/merged.csv")
```

The one tricky thing that we have to do here is to use `mapRowKeys`. When you read the frames, Deedle automatically generates ordinal row keys for your data and so merging would fail because you have two rows with a key `0`. The `mapRowKeys` function lets us transform the keys so that they are unique and the frames can be merged. (Saving the CSV file does not automatically write the row keys to the output, so the result of this is exactly what you wanted.)

Comment: Thanks Tomas, initially I planned to use Deedle to read csv files and merge them together but I tumbled into the RowKeys issue you mentioned. In the end, I used LumenWorksCsvReader to read csv files to Data.DataTable and merge them then convert to Deedle.Frame to save it to csv.
I have a list of files but I guess it would not be difficult to convert the "let merged" into function and using List.fold to merge all the files (not sure but will try), thanks for the answer

Comment: @JoseVu Thanks! Perhaps even easier trick would be to use composed row keys. For each frame, you could run something like `Frame.mapRowKeys (fun k -> "f1", k)` to add the name of the data frame (file) to the row key. This will avoid conflicts without messing with integer offsets.

Comment: Thanks Tomas,  that would work too, anyway I provided the code with List.fold in my question, didn't know that RowsKeys can be tuple

Answer (score 1):

If yo do a lot of processing like this you should look into the [CSV TypeProvider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) and [Parser](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html) or my favorite [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/).

If you don't want to use any third party libraries, here's a quick step-by-step process to read, re-assemble and write out the file:

```
open System.IO
open System

let csv1path = @"E:\tmp\csv1.csv"
let csv2path = @"E:\tmp\csv2.csv"

/// Read the file, split it up, and remove the header from the first csv file 
let csv1 = 
    File.ReadAllLines(csv1path)
    |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Split(','))
    |> Array.tail

let csv2 = 
    File.ReadAllLines(csv2path)
    |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Split(','))

///Split the header and data in the second csv file
let header', data = (csv2.[0], Array.tail csv2)
let header = String.Join(",", header')

///put back the data together, this is an array of arrays
let csv3 = 
    Array.append(csv1) data

///Sort the combined file, put it back together as a csv and add back the header   
let csv4 =
    csv3 
    |> Array.sort 
    |> Array.map (fun x -> String.Join(",", x))
    |> Array.append [|header|]

///Write it out
File.WriteAllLines(@"E:\tmp\combined.csv",csv4)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the "pure" solution you provided is really functional, however for my case there are many files (the 2 files case is just an example) the first csv file may have more columns the others file. I resolve by using some third-party packages: LumenWorksCsvReader to read csv files to Data.DataTable and using Deedle to save to csv file, I did try the FileHelpers as well but the CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv does not seem to be available in .Net Core

Comment: It's actually a somewhat procedural solution :-). You can easily add a function to get the longest header, and also map over al the csv files. That would indeed be a more functional solution. But I agree that you should use some helper library for these mundane tasks.

Comment: yes, I agree, the longest header might also not the full header, we can use the list.distinct of all headers but the merge function needs to rewrite and things get out of control, I agree we should use third-party for this mundane task, thanks for your comment